# Visual Studio: Unit Testing Universal Windows Class Libraries

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community edition:
I have created a Blank App (Universal Windows): The template is found in C# -> Windows -> Universal.

I have also a created a Class Library (Universal Windows) in the same solution: The template is found in C# -> Windows -> Universal

Now i intend to create a unit test project to test the Class Library i created earlier.

Now i do not see any unit test project templates in the Universal Windows section (they are all some kind of test apps or UI tests, not suitable for testing class libraries directly, i think).

So i tried creating a normal Unit Test project :(template is in C# -> test -> Unit Test Project)

And when i try to add a reference to the Class Library (Universal Windows) it complains it cannot add that project reference.

Can anyone suggest how i go about solving the problem?

Comment: just create a "unit test project" - unit tests projects are generally not shipped with your bits, so it doesn't really matter if it's not of the seemingly correct project type.

Comment: @Kritner Yeah, i did that and i mentioned it in my question too, that just threw an error and said can't add reference to project when i tried to add a reference to the class library.

Comment: What specific errors are you getting?

Comment: @Kritner How do i see the specific errors? it just shows a dialog saying can't add reference to project.

Comment: I am trying to do exactly the same thing and running into the exact same problem.

Comment: @zic10 I found that there is something called a unit test app (Universal Windows), this lets me add the reference to my universal windows class libraries, don't know what this unit test app does, but i figure it's the best i am going to get.